# javascript style display "none" not working

Tags: javascript, styles, display

I'm trying to hide or display html codes based on javascript if statement.

It's not working. You can see a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ajhv0pLj/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.localStorage.getItem("deflang") === null) {
    alert (window.localStorage.getItem("deflang"));
    document.getElementById('homepage').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>

<div id="homepage">
Hello world
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work because you had the `<script>` tags inside the `<script>` content... https://jsfiddle.net/ajhv0pLj/1/

Answer (score 1):

The code *is* working, you don't have to put the script tag around your javascript in jsfiddle, that's what's throwing the error.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Why should it be a comment, isn't it the answer to his problem? I don't think if something is a quick fix it should be a comment...

Comment: i see, anyway it was a typo. the problem still is here, it's not working in my full code. I'm using jquery-mobile.

Comment: So it's not working on mobile only then or do I not understand you correctly?

Comment: i found the solution, i had to put the script before the body tag close. Or just after my div declaration.

Comment: That's the problem with jsfiddle, we would've spotted that immediately, but we didn't see your original code... It's best practice to add your script before the closing body tag, because if a script is declared before your html content, your html content will wait until your script is loaded, that's not the best way to go. You want your content to load even without the script being already loaded for people who are on a poor internet connection (i.e. mobile phones on a train or something)

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, i had to put the script before the body tag close. Or just after my div declaration.

Basically, this worked:

```
<div id="homepage">
Hello world
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.localStorage.getItem("deflang") === null) {
    alert (window.localStorage.getItem("deflang"));
    document.getElementById('homepage').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```